# How to load a BGRA image texture in GLES2?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I have raw image in BGRA format.

I tried changing glTexImage2D format(7th arg) with GL_BGRA ,GL_BGRA_EXT ,GL_BGRA_IMG ,GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 ,Getting black image.

Below is the source used for loading the texture.7th argument changed with above values.

```
GLuint texture_object_id_1;
glGenTextures(1, &texture_object_id_1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_object_id_1);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, renderBufferWidth, renderBufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, osd_raw); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

If i try using GL_RGBA the texture color is bluish.
Any idea how to load a BGRA texture properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OpenGL ES 2 specification, `internalformat` must match `format`.

Try `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGRA, renderBufferWidth, renderBufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, osd_raw);`

Also, you can do whatever you want with texture data in shaders (including channels swap).

With OpenGL ES 3 you could also use `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_*` texture parameters.

Comment: @Rabbid76 That's why I wrote `With OpenGL ES 3` for texture swizzle. GL_BGRA comes from EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 extension, doesn't it?